# How to view, listen to, and download WhatsApp voice messages

Tags: twilio, whatsapp

I am trying to build a WhatsApp bot to collect voice messages sent in by users on Twilio. They do not need to be transcribed, just received and downloaded.

I can send and view media messages (photos and videos) sent on WhatsApp to my twilio number, but I am unable to view/listen to voice messages.

The code I am using to view such messages and the url they are stored at is:         `audio_url = str(request.form.get('MediaUrl0'))`

Has anyone experienced this before?/have a suggestion on how to fix?!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had a play around with this and got it to work. It seems that to download an audio message you need to:

- make an authenticated `GET` request to the `MediaUrl0`
- the response will be a 307 redirect, with a new location
- follow the redirect to the new location, or make a new request to the redirect location (this request doesn't seem to need authentication)

The `MediaUrl` redirects to a URL that looks like: `https://mms.twiliocdn.com/${ACCOUNT_SID}/${SOME_ID}`.

Comment: You’re welcome! And if this did help, please mark the answer as correct so that other people can see it helped too. Thanks!